# BLE android multiple sensors

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I actually have the project to develop an android application BLE which can connect and read multiple sensor (My version should be able to connect up to 7 devices, but I want to connect only 2 in the first time).

I read a lot of informations about that and have a knowledges of the global working-way (one thread by connection, queue of requests, etc) but I'm really not familiar with the JAVA language. I found arround a billion of topics with this subject but all of them are a bit old, so here is my questions :

- Does exists a working example which demontrate the implementation of this implementation's kind (One android with few exotics sensors like CC2650 Sensortag) ?
- To implement that application, should we create a library like Rami Martin did on his example : http://arissa34.github.io/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/
  or is it possible to create it without change the android library ?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy-to-use open sources libraries for BLE Android at the moment, almost of them are also not updated.
I also spent a long time to look for a good example and library, but all of them are one-device connection only. 
Finally, I went with this library.
https://github.com/RobotPajamas/Blueteeth
You can use this to connect with multiple devices easily. However, to get data from all of them, it is a little bit harder.

This is also not maintained currently but it is the best one for me. 
You can take a look at `sample-app` for more details.

Comment: Thank you Quang about your answer, I will take a look on it.

So a library seems obvious to connect multiple peripheral isn't it ?

Best regards,
John

Comment: Sure. I am using in my project. If you got struggle, please let me know. Make sure to check the sample project.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Quang, I will try to make a smoothie application with that.

Comment: @QuangNguyen Thanks for the reference to my library! I have updates in various feature branches (e.g. Kotlin), but haven't yet had the chance to hammer through updates... Hopefully this summer. It is a one-to-one library at the moment, but it could be used as a many-to-one library, assuming you keep a list of currently connected devices in the manager.

Comment: @SJoshi: Thank you for updates. Your library is great and works well for me. I have been using in my app which support multiple device connections with a manager (a wrapper) as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I do connect to several sensors but I just do it by connecting one after one, collect the data and disconnect then connect the next on etc... This is just working well. Isn't this OK for you?

Comment: Thank you about your answer.
It wasn't what I had in mind firstly but this si an interessant way to make it. If I don't succed I will probably test this solution.